# Create Category Grid Module for Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have Created Custom Category Grid Module for backend. But problem is that when I click on **Grid->Recipe (created module)** getting blank page.
so can anyone tell me what is the reason for getting blank page.
I am new in Magento and using **magento 1.9.2.3 version**. Below is the link of my custom grid.
  http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/admin/categoryrecipe/index/key/0630b5710a2a8926b253d04f755a684f/

Comment: why localhost link? provide your code in question

Comment: no one can help until  you show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are miss layout file so show blank page. you should add your layout file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/custom.xml`

Comment: already added layout file